# How do I get user geo location from a node js(express) server?

Tags: node.js, express, geolocation, ip

I need to build a project to get user's country or location. With front-end user needs to give permission which could be bothersome for the API calls.
Is there any way to get an **approximate location** of the user from their IP address in **node.js(express)** server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution could be to use APIs that return geoinformation for a given IP.
A sample could be this one which uses [ip-api](https://ipapi.co/api/)

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const port = 3000

app.post('/location_specific_service', async (req, res) => {
  var fetch_res = await fetch(`https://ipapi.co/${req.ip}/json/`);
  var fetch_data = await fetch_res.json()

  res.send(`You are from ${fetch_data.region}`)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```